# gtk+, "catch" a value from a function

Tags: linux, gtk

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int mcd();

static void num1( GtkWidget *entry1)
{
    const gchar* entry_text;
    entry_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY (entry1));
}

static void num2( GtkWidget *entry2)
{
    const gchar* entry_text;
    entry_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY (entry2));
}

//DA QUI...ho collegato il pulsante "Calcola" con la funzione MCD!
static void callback( GtkWidget *widget,
                      gpointer   data)
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=22;
    b=12;
    c=mcd(a,b);
    g_print("%d\n", c);
}

int mcd(int x, int y){
        if(y==0){
        return x;
        }
    else return mcd(y, x%y);
}
//A QUI

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *table;

  GtkWidget *label1;
  GtkWidget *label2;

  GtkWidget *entry1;
  GtkWidget *entry2;

  GtkWidget *button;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "MCD Calculator");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

  table = gtk_table_new(3, 2, FALSE);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);

  label1 = gtk_label_new("Num1:");
  label2 = gtk_label_new("Num2:");


  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0, 1, 1, 2, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);

  entry1 = gtk_entry_new();
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry1), "activate", G_CALLBACK(num1), &entry1);
  entry2 = gtk_entry_new();
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry2), "activate", G_CALLBACK(num2), &entry2);

  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry1, 1, 2, 0, 1, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry2, 1, 2, 1, 2, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);


   /*Pulsante calcola*/
   button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Calcola");
   gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
   gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE (table), button, 1, 5, 7, 8, GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND, GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND, 0, 0);
   g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (callback), (gpointer) "Calcola");
   /*Fine pulsante calcola*/

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I don't know how to catch the number from "entry_text" and "entry_text_1" and use them to callback function. (So it will become: a=entry_text; b=entry_text_1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying the access the text of the two `GtkEntry`s inside the button's `callback` function?  If so, you need to pass a reference to both to the button's signal handler.

So first, change this line:

```
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (callback), (gpointer) "Calcola");
```

To this:

```
GtkWidget *entries[2] = { entry1, entry 2};
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (callback), entries);
```

Then, in the `callback` function:

```
static void callback( GtkWidget *widget,
                  gpointer   data)
{
  GtkWidget *entries = data;
  int a,b,c;
  a=atoi(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entries[0])));
  b=atoi(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entries[1])));
  c=mcd(a,b);
  g_print("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: i've got this error,

error: cannot convert to a pointer type